# Options to migrate large database from Sybase ASE to SQL Server with minimum downtime

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sybase-ase, migration

The problem:

Our server database contains 1TB of data. It runs on a Sybase ASE 15.7 server and shall be migrated to SQL Server 2014. The servers will be located in the same data center during migration; an acceptable downtime is 6 hours.

We have considered using Sybase Replication Server, as we understand it, this product supports heterogeneous database replication from ASE to SQL. However; we do not have experience with this. Snapshot and transactional replication might be a possible solution.

We have some experience with SQL Server Migration Assistant and have successfully migrated the database objects and data in a test environment. However based on 8% test data, we have estimated that a complete migration of production database will take about 7 days. We can only have 6 hours downtime, and are not sure if this product can be used for data migration in our case. For database objects, this product has worked fine.

Do you have some recommendations to solve this problem?

Comment: There will always be a requirement to minimize downtime, so that doesn't really tell us anything.  How long can you be down?  Is your SQL Server up and running?  Do you have the ability to migrate and transactionally update?

Comment: Thanks for your question, I have update the problem description with more details.

Comment: Wats your Sql server hardware? Depending on that you can increase memory or multi threading maxdop configuration

Comment: The servers are hosted in ESX using a VPLEX SAN and ExtremIO SSDs. I believe we can optimize more, but I am not convinced we can do this in 6 hours with SSMA. As I understand it, for a consistent data migration, the database must be offline when we are using SSMA.

Comment: Replication Server transactional replication would likely be a good fit for your needs.  Once replication is initiated, the servers could be kept nearly identical until your cutover date.

Comment: Is there a way for you to segregate the data into stale and active and then migrate in tranches? In my experience large databases have upto 70% data that is there for historical reasons - reporting, analytics etc., which, if you can identify, can be moved ahead of time. In other words,
Can you identify the tables that do not change regularly and migrate them first? If that is not feasible, do the transactional tables have date fields in them so you can migrate the data upto a point and then migrate the rest of the rows during the cut over? The problem you will face with Sybase replication is t

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. 
I-We have staled/closed data, but they are not in separate tables and other active data can refer to staled data. I believe we can create one intermediate database with staled data, but we "cannot" create a separate active only database because of the references. Depending on the relation, it can be complicated to identify which data are active.  
II-Almost all tables do have date changed fields. Do you see problems with Sybase replication?